# Weird characters in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I wrote the following code :

```
 .386
 .model small
 .stack 100h

 .data
    text db "Paper",0
 .code
  start :

  lea dx , text
  mov ah , 9h
  int 21h

  mov ah , 4ch
  int 21h

  end start

  end
```

the problem is that it shows weird characters with the right sentence in the middle , what is exactly the problem ?

Comment: DS:DX = pointer to string ending in "$"

Comment: can you explain a little bit further ?

Comment: I can't resist asking: Why would you try to learn 16 bit assembly in 2013?

Comment: @user22323: It means that the string should be terminated by a '$'-character, not by NULL.

Comment: @user22323 - It means you should read the spec.  If not before coding, at least after, when things don't work right.

Comment: @Per Johansson - Because if you know assembler, you have a chance of understanding computing, and most people don't start reading with "War and Peace".

Comment: @PeterWright sure, but 16 bit is a weird choice. I assume the malfunction is (partly) due to segment registers, which more modern architecture avoids. And you can pretty much only run it in an emulator...

Comment: @PerJohansson: You can still run 16-bit apps in a 32-bit OS, and plenty of people are still running Windows XP 32-bit. There is a surprising amount of *good* assembly language tutorial stuff out there, and learning to call DOS interrupts is a good way to start. Otherwise you have to learn how to set up stack frames and such, which is a more advanced topic. 16-bit ASM is a good learning platform because of its simplicity. And you can avoid the whole segment thing by just setting them up at the start and leaving them.  Perfect for learning. Moving to 32-bit after learning 16-bit is quite easy.

Answer (score 3):

```
; your code
start:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
;your code
```

I think that'll solve your problem. Dos, when loading a .com file, sets `cs` = `ds` = `es`. Not so when loading an .exe format `cs` is pointed to your code, of course, but `ds` (and `es`?) are pointed to your PSP (Program Segment Prefix), which is typically not where your data lives... You have to set up `ds` (and `es` if you're going to use it) yourself.

"Why learn 16-bit assembly?" is a good question. "Why learn assembly at all?" is another good question. Chances are you'll never write anything "serious" with it. But it allows you to learn what goes on "under the hood" in a way that HLLs won't, and 16-bit allows you to understand the segmented memory model. 32-bit code is segmented, too, but while the segments are "different" they generally point to the same memory and you can generally ignore 'em - the OS takes care of all that for you.

Besides, some of us are crazy enough to think it's fun!