# Weird garbage in output

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

So I im using tasm 1.4 and I was making a program to bring out CS14 in big made up in smaller letters and numbers. about 1/4 of the the way through I ran it and some weird stuff comes up after the output of my last msg saying stuff like hgweh26I^U%EYWGT#YWHSDWrite disk FullHSJETESRGDTFHGJ!

the error looks like this
http://s18.postimg.org/h35196kop/TD2.png

This is my code(Although its not done yet):

```
MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
MSG DB 27  DUP('*'),13,10
MSG1  DB 27  DUP('*'),13,10
MSG2  DB 3 DUP('*')
MSG3  DB 2 DUP(' ')
MSG4  DB 3 DUP('C')
MSG5  DB 2 DUP(' ')
MSG6  DB 4 DUP('S')
MSG7  DB 2 DUP(' ')
MSG8  DB '1'
MSG9  DB 2 DUP(' ')
MSG10  DB '4 4'
MSG11  DB 2 DUP(' ')
MSG12  DB 3 DUP('*'),13,10
.CODE
MAIN PROC
;INIT
MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX
;DISPLAY
LEA DX, MSG
MOV AH, 9
INT 21H
;RETURN TO DOS
MOV AX, 4C00H
INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Weird characters in assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136679/weird-characters-in-assembly)

Answer (score 2):

Strings printed with [`INT 21H / AH=09H`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) are supposed to be terminated by a `'$'`-character (ASCII code 36). I don't see any such terminator after your strings, so the interrupt function will just keep on printing until the terminator is found.

Comment: So I just add the dollar sign by itself after each string or at the end when its finished printing all the strings? Also how would I add it? Like this?   ,'$' or like this ,$ or what?

Comment: You put it where you want the string to end when printed. And it would be `,'$'`

Comment: BTW is there a better way to do this than by making a 100 MSG?

Comment: Well, it would definitely be easier to just type out all the strings the way you want them to look on the console instead of using `DUP`.